# Vault not found in the subscription error occurs randomly azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am updating key vault access policies from azure devops yaml pipeline. below is the standard code.

```
       - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Set KeyVault access policy for Web App"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: "$(serviceConnection1)"
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            az keyvault set-policy -n '$(KeyVaultName)' --secret-permissions get list --object-id '$(appId)'
```

The task succeeds but also fails lot of times with an error

"vault not found in the subscription" . The service principle has contributor rights to the keyvault.

Network of keyvault is set to "All Networks" ,hence no firewall rules.

I am pretty certain, there is no technical error here, but the task fails quite a lot of times with this error. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let us know whether the answers below can help you and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 4):

This occurs when there are too many vaults in the subscription.
For example, if I run
`az keyvault show --name $keyvaultName --resource-group "$azureSubscription-rg"` it works fine, if I then run `az keyvault set-policy --name $keyvaultName --object-id $principalObjectId --secret-permissions all` it errors saying vault not found. What I discovered with `--debug` is the payload received is large and doesn't contain the vault I'm looking for with set-policy.

What worked for me was this
`az keyvault set-policy --name $keyvaultName --object-id $principalObjectId --secret-permissions all --resource-group "$azureSubscription-rg"`

Answer (score 2):

Your Azure SPN that you are using must have access to multiple subscriptions and hence this happens when suddenly the SPN has the default context in some other subcription. Better to tell AZCLI explicitly which one to use
Suggested, try this out
Add **"az account set --subscription '$(serviceConnection1)'"**

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Set KeyVault access policy for Web App"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: "$(serviceConnection1)"
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            az account set --subscription '$(serviceConnection1)'
            az keyvault set-policy -n '$(KeyVaultName)' --secret-permissions get list --object-id '$(appId)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [sikumars-msft | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/sikumars-msft/) . Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

Ideally, we receive the message  `The Vault '$KeyVaultName' not found within subscription`
when the supplied name does not match a vault that is available in Azure.
Thus we would recommend that you use the `--debug` parameter in combination with the above cmdlet which provides more insight from key aspects

```
az keyvault set-policy -n {TypeKeyVaultName} --secret-permissions get list --object-id $(appId) --debug
```

Reference: [Vault not found in the subscription error occurs randomly azure devops pipeline - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760396/vault-not-found-in-the-subscription-error-occurs-r.html)